# django - list of lists in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to render a list of lists zipped with `zip()`.

```
list_of_list = zip(location,rating,images)
```

I want to render this `list_of_list` to template and want to show only the first image of each location.

my location and image models are these:

```
class Location(models.Model):
  locationname = models.CharField

class Image(models.Model):
  of_location = ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locs_image")
  img = models.ImageField(upload_to=".",default='')
```

here is the zipped list. How can I access only the first image of each location in template?

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why are you zipping actually? Why not use relationships?

Comment: @Bibhas, you mean: 
``all_locations = Location.objects.all()`` and in template ``{% for loc in all_locations %} {% for img in loc.locs_image.all %}{{img.img.name}} {% endfor %}  {% endfor %}`` ?

Comment: Yes. Why not that? And if you want just one item, you can use `slice` tag in templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the `list_of_lists` to the RequestContext. Then you can reference the first index of the `images` list in your template:

```
{% for location, rating, images in list_of_lists %}

...
<img>{{ images.0 }}</img>
...

{% endfor %}
```

[How to render a context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context)

Comment: Can you show your render-function and the part of your template that you're targeting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at  [django-multiforloop](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/django-multiforloop).

Answer (score 0):

**You can handle list elements in your template also based on their type (with Django 1.11 ).**

So in case you have the view you describe:

```py
# view.py
# ...
list_of_lists = zip(location,rating,images)
context['list_of_lists'] = list_of_lists
# ...
```

All you need to do is **create a tag to determine the type of your elements** in the template:

```
# tags.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def get_type(value):
    return type(value).__name__
```

Then you can detect the content type of a list element and **only display the first element if the list element is a list itself**:

```
{% load tags %}
{# ...other things #}
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>locationname</th>
    <th>rating</th>
    <th>images</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    {% for a_list in list_of_lists %}
    {% for an_el in a_list %}
    <td>
        {# if it is a list only take the first element #}
        {% if an_el|get_type == 'list' %}
        {{ an_el.0 }}
        {% else %}
        {{ an_el }}
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  % endfor %}
</tbody>
```