# Django returned response not updating in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I send some of the dropdown values from my ajax to Django views, the Django views returning a  response in JSON format. The value is a list of the list according to python so in javascript it's an array of arrays. What I want to do is to parse the data coming from the Django views and update a div content in the front end.

This is what I tried so far:

`filter.html`

```
<form id="form1" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div classs="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <label for="intent">Intent</label>
                <div class="styled-select blue semi-square">
                    <select name="intent" id="intent-sel">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="opinion">Opinion</option>
                        <option value="complaint">Complaint</option>
                        <option value="suggestion">Suggestion</option>
                        <option value="satisfied">Satisfied</option>
                        <option value="delivery">Delivery</option>
                        <option value="customer_sensitivity_for_pricing">SensitivityForPricing</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <label for="product-type">Product Type</label>
                <div class="styled-select blue semi-square">
                    <select name="product_type" id="product-sel">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="condom">Condom</option>
                        <option value="lube">Lubricant</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <label for="rating">Rating</label>
                <div class="styled-select blue semi-square">
                    <select name="rating" id="rating-sel">
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
                        <option value="2">2 Star</option>
                        <option value="3">3 Star</option>
                        <option value="4">4 Star</option>
                        <option value="5">5 Star</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <label for="brand">brand</label>
                    <div class="styled-select blue semi-square">
                        <select name="brand" id="brand-sel">
                            <option value="all">All</option>
                            <option value="durex">Durex</option>
                            <option value="skore">Skore</option>
                            <option value="kamasutra">KamaSutra</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonHolder">
        <button type="submit" id='upload-button' class="btn btn btn-outline-dark">Filter</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="content_data">
    </div>
</form>
<script>
        $(document).on('submit', '#form1',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{% url "filter" %}',
        data:{
            intent:$('#intent-sel').val(),
            product_type:$('#product-sel').val(),
            rating:$('#rating-sel').val(),
            brand: $('#brand-sel').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        success:function(json){
            document.getElementById("form1").reset();
            console.log(json);
            $("#content_data").prepend('<div class="col-md-6">'+'<p class="mb-auto">' + "jlksjlf" + '</p>' +
                    '</div>'
            )
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log("error:");
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

`views.py`

```
def filter(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        intent = request.POST.get('intent')
        product_type = request.POST.get('product_type')
        rating = request.POST.get('rating')
        brand = request.POST.get('brand')
        data = filter_result(intent, product_type, rating, brand)

        context = {"data": data}

        return JsonResponse(context)
    return render(request, 'filter.html')
```

How can I achive the result?

Comment: Welcome to S/O. Can you please explain what you mean by this ```The value is a list of the list according to python so in javascript it's an array of arrays. ```?

Comment: The value I am passing from my Django views i.e data is an array of arrays like `[['a','b','c], [1,2,3], ['d', 'e', 'f']]`

Comment: From what I understand, you are passing a list of lists to the front-end  which you want to be able to render in the templates. If so, u dont need to do a JsonResponse, see this for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703945/django-list-of-lists-in-template

Comment: But I want that list of list to appear after the POST request and update a div in the front end with that list of list data, any solution for that?